# laravelのログイン機能について

Tags: php, laravel

laravelのログイン処理で使用するAuthenticatesUsers.phpファイル内の下記の処理がどのように動いているのかがわかりません教えてください。

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
        );
    }

protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    }
```

Comment: 具体的にどのような部分がわからないのでしょうか？

Comment: attemptLoginクラスの処理の流れがわかりません